# Here Map hangs the main activity

Tags: java, android, here-api

I am using HERE map Android SDK (90 days trail) in my application. I observed that my main activity gets hanged after some time. When I checked logs from Android DDMS tool, whenever main activity is in hanged state, main thread was in MONITOR state and was working on some map activity. Here is some sample log

```
 at com.nokia.maps.MapImpl.getZoomLevel(Native Method)
 at com.nokia.maps.ag.a(ClusterLayerImpl.java:221)
 at com.nokia.maps.ag.onMapTransformEnd(ClusterLayerImpl.java:207)
 at com.nokia.maps.MapImpl$8.run(MapImpl.java:1999)  
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)  
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)  
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)  
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5127)  
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller. 
 run   (ZygoteInit.java:825)  
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Note that if i don't use cluster with Map then this error goes away but Map still hangs with some different map activity ( e.g `setNativeMapCentric`). However after removing cluster, app start responding after waiting 2-3 seconds.

EDIT - 1

Added some Log Dumps

```
03-30 16:27:34.229 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M AAD09000 00000000 0000F000 FAFEFC8E62239754827CE97D13B7408D0 libandroid.so
03-30 16:27:34.229 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M AAD1C000 00000000 00007000 0DCF99F939F3936BBF944A25BAA095D40 libgpu_aux.so
03-30 16:27:34.229 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M AAD25000 00000000 00003000 B2DE7AE30D9632FBAF4003F74C5A291A0 libmtk_mali_user.so
03-30 16:27:34.230 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M AAD28000 00000000 0011C000 35B15CA53D69D771FCAE1021340EAFB60 libGLES_mali.so
03-30 16:27:34.230 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M AB443000 0001A000 00010000 000000000000000000000000000000000 FwkPlugin.odex
03-30 16:27:34.230 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M AB451000 00000000 00021000 FCCC4ECC8D31CBC394AD5F670825D0510 libexif.so
03-30 16:27:34.230 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M AB50C000 00000000 00005000 891BC56E64F87001F4B6AD1BE4D41AF70 libauroservice_client.so
03-30 16:27:34.230 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M AB512000 00000000 00046000 4D4AFCCF057144F91F967352D056DD850 libmedia_jni.so
03-30 16:27:34.230 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M ACC56000 00000000 0000E000 800E1D146A4BCF348265F6A6C849D8750 libstagefright_amrnb_common.so
03-30 16:27:34.230 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M ACC66000 00000000 00015000 C8E0CCA8E30F454A41A4B5BE33A8602D0 libmtp.so
03-30 16:27:34.230 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M AF487000 00000000 0000B000 9848A94B1BF17C52342C00E46D1C4AAE0 libjhead.so
03-30 16:27:34.231 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M AF496000 00000000 00018000 7EAB0A48D6F706A6D3D2929F2A89CA1C0 libkeymaster1.so
03-30 16:27:34.231 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M AF4B1000 00000000 00009000 33859FBCDE8B9F3FCA6E64F5603EDD460 libkeymaster_messages.so
03-30 16:27:34.231 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M AF4BC000 00000000 00014000 F6C51E7C925C709B8C1EF35499BABD840 libsoftkeymasterdevice.so
03-30 16:27:34.231 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M AF4D3000 00000000 0000B000 55F1E6B6EF38114CFF740044A1D27CFC0 libkeystore_binder.so
03-30 16:27:34.231 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M AF4E1000 00000000 00004000 22FBCE8FF0CD51CB1AFFD6A64DADED250 libkeystore-engine.so
03-30 16:27:34.231 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M AF4E6000 00000000 00018000 EDC63A167BE16BA5730461B3D3D578580 libjavacrypto.so
03-30 16:27:34.231 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M AF6E5000 00000000 00004000 118526F7ABC5BBF58FB3A5B7D6A2027D0 memtrack.mt6580.so
03-30 16:27:34.233 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M AF862000 00000000 00002000 02A5CD46BE9695C2143B6B9B36EF92850 libos_adaptation.context.so
03-30 16:27:34.233 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B1188000 00000000 00034000 DED779939C61000D045B254B5F2190470 libjavacore.so
03-30 16:27:34.233 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B3922000 00000000 00015000 FD999DFF8EE3753AC280B0E09E789D170 libgui_ext.so
03-30 16:27:34.233 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B3AD2000 00000000 00009000 5E70341927977119BD4FE891B69BE4E50 gralloc.mt6580.so
03-30 16:27:34.233 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B3E8A000 00000000 00005000 5A122E10741EE0FCC278F5CEDECE33AB0 libperfservicenative.so
03-30 16:27:34.233 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B4338000 00000000 00003000 4475340E5BBC439731FF93023C37AF950 libsigchain.so
03-30 16:27:34.233 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B432F000 00000000 00443000 F6D9303A5E8B2D729A5ECD046A45FD580 libart.so
03-30 16:27:34.233 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B48A9000 00000000 0003D000 9842FF5368F684C8E3DB68F3F1E4715F0 libfs_mgr.so
03-30 16:27:34.234 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B48E9000 00000000 00004000 BC12B3D485F0C7E9FBEC470A85CE51490 libnvram_sec.so
03-30 16:27:34.234 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B48EF000 00000000 00003000 F2A1F845E0A91CE7C40C7A96A64804B00 libnvram_platform.so
03-30 16:27:34.234 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B48F4000 00000000 00004000 7F8F8A092B5F2FFCF766B1C1E924846B0 libcustom_nvram.so
03-30 16:27:34.234 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B4907000 00000000 00038000 B7785D679F841C55A7E68ED1A94566DC0 libmtkjpeg.so
03-30 16:27:34.234 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B4941000 00000000 00010000 CEF3D7B9E3201D957C27D79DF633C7D30 libnvram.so
03-30 16:27:34.234 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B4954000 00000000 0000B000 A6A06A3D2DF6A6D271A6DBF250534ACB0 libbwc.so
03-30 16:27:34.234 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B4962000 00000000 00005000 E4200DA11C0DAFE5A14043FD21E7F8EA0 libSwJpgCodec.so
03-30 16:27:34.234 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B496A000 00000000 00006000 D28A5859585A533357109A0D731BDA3A0 libnvramagentclient.so
03-30 16:27:34.234 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B4973000 00000000 00005000 4CADAEBF4E5EB7FD9F854EAA85913B590 libdrmmtkwhitelist.so
03-30 16:27:34.234 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B4957000 00000000 00A35000 79A07E31B35FAFA1F73D1ADB9281B8820 libLLVM.so
03-30 16:27:34.235 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B53DF000 00000000 00035000 DB4231AADE91CF25035C6D69EF525F950 libbcinfo.so
03-30 16:27:34.235 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B5417000 00000000 00058000 8C085A8DFD4D0FD76EE2CBE31D8545C50 libbcc.so
03-30 16:27:34.236 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B5472000 00000000 00002000 E8199316C77A26228B24F1E281EA39BD0 libvcodec_oal.so
03-30 16:27:34.236 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B5476000 00000000 0000E000 53B957D5A01FCE6EB72A596A8EE2CDF60 libvcodec_utility.so
03-30 16:27:34.236 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B5490000 00000000 0000B000 940801FB4578671713A2E3C5280874BD0 libcommon_time_client.so
03-30 16:27:34.237 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B549F000 00000000 00012000 95A164C918F51BD6EE141F6BFF75A56F0 libnl.so
03-30 16:27:34.237 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B54B4000 00000000 00017000 D879D6FB0CB2C0E15CC5809D1909D4A80 libprotobuf-cpp-lite.so
03-30 16:27:34.237 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B54CE000 00000000 0000C000 C12CABF09FB0497FEDA0C32C29ACFDD30 libpq_prot.so
03-30 16:27:34.237 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B54DC000 00000000 0000E000 9BE96ADF671641AC1F430A5A87DF5F080 libpqservice.so
03-30 16:27:34.237 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B54EE000 00000000 00003000 D3A7ADD9DC5E57D9DD835E4D671D1FA90 libion_mtk.so
03-30 16:27:34.237 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B54F4000 00000000 00005000 14F1919D8B0A632C093AC82BD132461A0 libm4u.so
03-30 16:27:34.237 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B54FB000 00000000 00003000 FA942BD769D9EB485A8208B429B566F60 libion.so
03-30 16:27:34.237 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B5500000 00000000 00008000 2283B17FE94EB0B7C7480520270354F60 libJpgDecPipe.so
03-30 16:27:34.237 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B550A000 00000000 00004000 3BFF08B7131D0F221FB90D0E220B2AA90 libmrdump.so
03-30 16:27:34.237 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B550E000 00000000 00086000 B95C9AB336117E23264B4F2CD25B6D280 libdrmmtkutil.so
03-30 16:27:34.238 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B559B000 00000000 00004000 592DD48F8F226CF7819235036AAAE33C0 libcustom_prop.so
03-30 16:27:34.238 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B55A4000 00000000 00007000 92BB25CF120BB0917D486285A90C0EEC0 libstagefright_avc_common.so
03-30 16:27:34.238 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B55AD000 00000000 00003000 FF2B237A4605434611C7E9D2ACDF92AF0 libstagefright_enc_common.so
03-30 16:27:34.238 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B55B2000 00000000 00004000 7BF27939F33F9E4F80BB1E2772ECD2360 libpowermanager.so
03-30 16:27:34.238 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B55B9000 00000000 0001C000 C7F282DCABD418E7941D6064E01C60AF0 libvorbisidec.so
03-30 16:27:34.238 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B55D7000 00000000 00005000 BF017306633BD8FE06D122FCA89954F30 libstagefright_yuv.so
03-30 16:27:34.238 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B55DD000 00000000 00030000 A4E196FFCC7DB082DB7D9C98AB6696130 libstagefright_omx.so
03-30 16:27:34.238 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B5611000 00000000 00039000 4C2DA9FA2837C1131E54622854ABE9080 libopus.so
03-30 16:27:34.238 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B564C000 00000000 00005000 41DFEAACD1A2BF0BC2AB3A4D48B9589F0 libmediautils.so
03-30 16:27:34.238 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B5653000 00000000 00017000 CBC2EA991A9B69C74872E39194F142620 libdrmframework.so
03-30 16:27:34.239 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B566F000 00000000 0001E000 DEB182A5251B9462097C2B4A73C7565A0 libRScpp.so
03-30 16:27:34.239 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B5690000 00000000 0003E000 8B65E7A42BDF4792CFD44CD8500597C40 libRS.so
03-30 16:27:34.239 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B56D2000 00000000 00005000 BFC93F5F229D37071851BA4FA70A945F0 libmtk_drvb.so
03-30 16:27:34.239 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B56D9000 00000000 00003000 9016B1D5E3363A248B9523F679FCBED70 libmtksqlite3_custom.so
03-30 16:27:34.239 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B56DE000 00000000 00006000 9FD691A38F12F1FDE5C10F63295BFCEF0 libspeexresampler.so
03-30 16:27:34.239 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B56E7000 00000000 0002F000 7CD890A1ACBC67922ADCF6696145BACA0 libvcodecdrv.so
03-30 16:27:34.239 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B5741000 00000000 00009000 72B9C6E9F506E37FE0DA31EC00031A120 libnbaio.so
03-30 16:27:34.239 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B574C000 00000000 00009000 541346AD76B3EDB4225ED7FDA07032C00 libsysutils.so
03-30 16:27:34.239 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B5758000 00000000 00012000 770F189D702C1498EAAB156231258B020 libpcre.so
03-30 16:27:34.239 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B576C000 00000000 00005000 229984629EA4D8434EC79A31C52F616E0 libwpa_client.so
03-30 16:27:34.240 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B5774000 00000000 0006D000 C83C6B3CADC9A1074A14471467CF9F060 libGLES_trace.so
03-30 16:27:34.240 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B57E4000 00000000 00052000 9A1C61EE7108F8B08B6378D75D4DE5350 libdpframework.so
03-30 16:27:34.240 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B5839000 00000000 00003000 8BFA6AB5132BAF5CCFB7DB4E486598FF0 libmhalImageCodec.so
03-30 16:27:34.240 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B583E000 00000000 0005D000 D99BBA7E1ED8E9047B58903E4F737C420 libft2.so
03-30 16:27:34.240 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B589E000 00000000 00028000 85BFB3FE4DB2AE5A3350448B44A24F290 libpng.so
03-30 16:27:34.240 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B58C8000 00000000 00005000 E81048E18329E5945E198E6A0D7D5C520 libtouchfilter.so
03-30 16:27:34.240 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B58D0000 00000000 00004000 3102EE3D8D1B8197C35F0CFEA6BE93F30 libgralloc_extra.so
03-30 16:27:34.240 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B58D8000 00000000 0000B000 3B69C127EC7A22B1C38506F02367DD300 libui_ext.so
03-30 16:27:34.240 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B58E6000 00000000 00003000 61563472610E8C759C1BD9366285D6740 libsync.so
03-30 16:27:34.242 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B58EB000 00000000 00012000 02D71DDF0CA2BA24F96BD9A29E9EA9510 libaed.so
03-30 16:27:34.242 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B5907000 00000000 00005000 DF0F7522D87D7BCFE55F1BC09D278FFA0 libstdc++.so
03-30 16:27:34.243 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B590E000 00000000 00010000 ED48E9480B7FDDCF3A803A9A0A904B620 libunwind.so
03-30 16:27:34.243 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B5968000 00000000 00009000 7278CE19019120E50EBFC364C6C2E1C10 libbase.so
03-30 16:27:34.243 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B5973000 00000000 00005000 02B03AD2034827DA4CAA945A789B27E20 libeffects.so
03-30 16:27:34.243 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B597A000 00000000 00003000 473C72E4F9E84A4F8B65D051683DE5A10 libstagefright_http_support.so
03-30 16:27:34.243 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B5980000 00000000 0001B000 36815A08B083B812B57274FC5BA532820 libstagefright_foundation.so
03-30 16:27:34.243 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B5995000 00000000 0024E000 E1AB684A56DFEDCA383B4488F07B565E0 libstagefright.so
03-30 16:27:34.244 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B5BF4000 00000000 00079000 BCE9EAEE52B2B334C7B2CE55149AC8020 libhwui.so
03-30 16:27:34.244 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B5C73000 00000000 0000A000 C09174B81332BEF21FE3CC04804A05E70 libmtkcamera_client.so
03-30 16:27:34.244 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B5C7F000 00000000 00007000 A67068AFEE9B15086C97D3E444D003700 libmtksqlite3_android.so
03-30 16:27:34.244 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B5C88000 00000000 00003000 C99382BD2B5F2A60742568B35D60FEBB0 libradio_metadata.so
03-30 16:27:34.244 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B5C8D000 00000000 00004000 633D0303F2DE1E9E135BBF4ABF1A1DA30 libnativebridge.so
03-30 16:27:34.244 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B5C93000 00000000 00004000 A311A79CDF137504F148B22D5501E2D00 libprocessgroup.so
03-30 16:27:34.244 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B5C99000 00000000 0000F000 C3D87A05A8B44AF0A80E127F55AECCFA0 libminikin.so
03-30 16:27:34.245 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B5CA9000 00000000 0000B000 79E5541FF97300C3AA5AEA30DD267EC90 libsoundtrigger.so
03-30 16:27:34.245 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B5CB8000 00000000 0000B000 3777619272DA4EEFF57F5933395570A80 libradio.so
03-30 16:27:34.245 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B5CC7000 00000000 00004000 715F97E2E344BA93F2ECBE0DB8A07A2C0 libnetd_client.so
03-30 16:27:34.245 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B5CCD000 00000000 0000D000 C540B1E1D9FA98D59AEA58FD79E4ECDC0 libimg_utils.so
03-30 16:27:34.245 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B5CD7000 00000000 00401000 845A51CFEAFF7C43A2D97FB6A2687D5C0 libpdfium.so
03-30 16:27:34.245 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B60E7000 00000000 00007000 942D08E695D1EFEB68FF763034BC4EE40 libaudioutils.so
03-30 16:27:34.245 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B60F0000 00000000 0001A000 28AE68E5AE451B45CB9B00AA3A3D469D0 libz.so
03-30 16:27:34.245 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B610C000 00000000 00067000 AA9644FDA4B6FA18981A73035E6C75780 libharfbuzz_ng.so
03-30 16:27:34.245 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B6176000 00000000 00004000 7C467F236EB2A84B34F8E2080A83E79C0 libusbhost.so
03-30 16:27:34.246 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B617D000 00000000 00036000 EFE9CB9C74B2120AF66B116284F1AC2B0 libjpeg.so
03-30 16:27:34.246 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B619B000 00000000 000C6000 A9EB307B59EC45ED93FF5FED88204FC30 libmedia.so
03-30 16:27:34.246 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B627A000 00000000 0016B000 B2AB76649350C30C2594FDEB3D52961E0 libicui18n.so
03-30 16:27:34.246 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B63EA000 00000000 00115000 D3539F6C3EB9178C15260547F8A5C77C0 libicuuc.so
03-30 16:27:34.246 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B650F000 00000000 0002B000 D3FF2003B2CBC9BFE6137E480D9AB96F0 libssl.so
03-30 16:27:34.246 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B6536000 00000000 000A3000 7CEFDE7712A7C22C5E4C3EA022C7100E0 libcrypto.so
03-30 16:27:34.246 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B65E6000 00000000 00053000 8951A3833180D05A06149C7762644BF50 libsonivox.so
03-30 16:27:34.246 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B6641000 00000000 0000E000 0EC1F6BB296D73754D2F348B8B13DFE50 libselinux.so
03-30 16:27:34.246 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B6652000 00000000 00007000 50A0C044CDCB127097234A46B90D58CA0 libhardware_legacy.so
03-30 16:27:34.247 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B665C000 00000000 00003000 9BDFDDAFFE56616439788C36E458EE790 libhardware.so
03-30 16:27:34.247 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B6661000 00000000 00004000 671400440AFACC6A43BB1CBB83555BF40 libETC1.so
03-30 16:27:34.247 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B6667000 00000000 0000D000 BE06F1783B6E84C1EC4C85CD4DD0C32D0 libGLESv2.so
03-30 16:27:34.247 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B6676000 00000000 00008000 D59B398873B95D262BE2F4B718E3DEEE0 libGLESv1_CM.so
03-30 16:27:34.247 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B6678000 00000000 00064000 B3E9FA42ECDF9013B569D77846D97B1C0 libEGL.so
03-30 16:27:34.247 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B66EA000 00000000 00063000 4ECEC15350CF120EF58FB48E0D04A50F0 libsqlite.so
03-30 16:27:34.247 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B673F000 00000000 003C7000 D038920685BC91CF1D9116F5E587A8060 libskia.so
03-30 16:27:34.247 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B6B27000 00000000 00008000 A2262364B49B35739CFF795B8445EE730 libcamera_metadata.so
03-30 16:27:34.247 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B6B2C000 00000000 0002A000 0BBA972AE43849B0C7AC7E1AEAF710CA0 libcamera_client.so
03-30 16:27:34.247 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B6B5E000 00000000 00040000 3793499B6E565AD0DDE00A46D1F0CD3F0 libinputflinger.so
03-30 16:27:34.248 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B6BA1000 00000000 0001D000 6A48354E04BBBA0AD2A6AB60E2F7F18B0 libinput.so
03-30 16:27:34.248 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B6BB9000 00000000 00061000 CDCD24B510B16B4593908005FD8543800 libgui.so
03-30 16:27:34.248 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B6C29000 00000000 00014000 0D39E12A7EBF9DE4A932D0325D1CEF470 libui.so
03-30 16:27:34.248 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B6C41000 00000000 0000A000 853A7750197CD04A49D0155088A1EE7B0 libnetutils.so
03-30 16:27:34.248 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B6C4D000 00000000 00007000 502F3A8CD4471646F65AE1AECBB9DCDA0 libnativehelper.so
03-30 16:27:34.248 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B6C56000 00000000 00014000 D25AD7D350D7303A8BA07362B9695C580 libexpat.so
03-30 16:27:34.248 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B6C6D000 00000000 00028000 01E09F78EBAEFE14ABB8F5F42ABEA6920 libandroidfw.so
03-30 16:27:34.248 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B6C98000 00000000 00003000 071E9A38A7C00F46C84990CAA570A9570 libmemtrack.so
03-30 16:27:34.248 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B6C9D000 00000000 00009000 10E5AB002E5314E0D326597EDCDFF48B0 libbacktrace.so
03-30 16:27:34.248 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B6CA8000 00000000 0001F000 0CAC6218872A6DC45FF6634932B22F050 libm.so
03-30 16:27:34.249 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B6CCA000 00000000 00074000 81F77816722BA7643D2DED9D639808B60 libc.so
03-30 16:27:34.249 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B6D4D000 00000000 0008A000 5329FC87BB63CBE2511F17C8D17BF9690 libc++.so
03-30 16:27:34.249 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B6DDD000 00000000 00029000 7F575A9EA5DDAC0700645C5D7AB43A370 libwilhelm.so
03-30 16:27:34.249 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B6DFC000 00000000 000E2000 AE8FA833FBAB3BF275B8D52170CA56790 libandroid_runtime.so
03-30 16:27:34.249 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B6EEF000 00000000 00029000 0E6EB7D5C77E292BCB25D126B832ECD90 libbinder.so
03-30 16:27:34.249 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B6F21000 00000000 00008000 6FAC08BB3CE194CC1857288397BC3D960 liblog.so
03-30 16:27:34.249 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B6F2B000 00000000 00018000 D1936E134561887D07655F7DC0DF31DF0 libutils.so
03-30 16:27:34.250 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B6F45000 00000000 0000F000 D6012254A1BA9EBA57B93382940E8E240 libcutils.so
03-30 16:27:34.250 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: M B6F81000 00000000 0001D000 0385C7CE356C3A5AC4A69DA0186660D30 linker
03-30 16:27:34.250 2692-2635/? A/google-breakpad: -----END BREAKPAD MICRODUMP-----
03-30 16:27:34.281 956-2635/com.pretlist.p2p.app A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x90040010 in tid 2635 (BaseTextureView)
03-30 16:27:34.345 2698-2698/? A/AEE/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
03-30 16:27:34.345 2698-2698/? A/AEE/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'Micromax/Q386/Q386:6.0/MRA58K/1461117601:user/release-keys'
03-30 16:27:34.345 2698-2698/? A/AEE/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
03-30 16:27:34.345 2698-2698/? A/AEE/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
03-30 16:27:34.346 2698-2698/? A/AEE/DEBUG: pid: 956, tid: 2635, name: BaseTextureView  >>> com.pretlist.p2p.app <<<
03-30 16:27:34.346 2698-2698/? A/AEE/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x90040010
03-30 16:27:34.389 2698-2698/? A/AEE/DEBUG:     r0 73f1cf24  r1 7b1949cd  r2 8fd97098  r3 90040020
03-30 16:27:34.389 2698-2698/? A/AEE/DEBUG:     r4 ef0b18f2  r5 ffffffff  r6 8fd97098  r7 8fd97098
03-30 16:27:34.389 2698-2698/? A/AEE/DEBUG:     r8 00000020  r9 8fd99120  sl 91070464  fp 910704ac
03-30 16:27:34.390 2698-2698/? A/AEE/DEBUG:     ip 000003e8  sp 91070460  lr 00045745  pc 9e0d1d0c  cpsr 200f0010
03-30 16:27:34.460 2698-2698/? A/AEE/DEBUG: backtrace:
03-30 16:27:34.460 2698-2698/? A/AEE/DEBUG:     #00 pc 0028ed0c  /data/app/com.pretlist.p2p.app-1/lib/arm/libMAPSJNI.so
03-30 16:27:34.461 2698-2698/? A/AEE/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0029106c  /data/app/com.pretlist.p2p.app-1/lib/arm/libMAPSJNI.so
03-30 16:27:34.461 2698-2698/? A/AEE/DEBUG:     #02 pc 0157d3df  /data/app/com.pretlist.p2p.app-1/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0x9d1000) (void com.nokia.maps.NmaaGestureHandler.pollNative(long)+82)
03-30 16:27:34.461 2698-2698/? A/AEE/DEBUG:     #03 pc 0157c849  /data/app/com.pretlist.p2p.app-1/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0x9d1000) (void com.nokia.maps.NmaaGestureHandler.a(com.nokia.maps.NmaaGestureHandler, long)+68)
03-30 16:27:34.461 2698-2698/? A/AEE/DEBUG:     #04 pc 0157bcfb  /data/app/com.pretlist.p2p.app-1/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0x9d1000) (void com.nokia.maps.NmaaGestureHandler$a.a()+286)
03-30 16:27:34.461 2698-2698/? A/AEE/DEBUG:     #05 pc 0157dea5  /data/app/com.pretlist.p2p.app-1/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0x9d1000) (void com.nokia.maps.NmaaGestureHandler.a()+104)
03-30 16:27:34.461 2698-2698/? A/AEE/DEBUG:     #06 pc 016f9c4b  /data/app/com.pretlist.p2p.app-1/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0x9d1000) (void com.nokia.maps.ch$6.a()+318)
03-30 16:27:34.461 2698-2698/? A/AEE/DEBUG:     #07 pc 016a89a3  /data/app/com.pretlist.p2p.app-1/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0x9d1000) (void com.nokia.maps.cd.l()+390)
03-30 16:27:34.461 2698-2698/? A/AEE/DEBUG:     #08 pc 016a92df  /data/app/com.pretlist.p2p.app-1/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0x9d1000) (void com.nokia.maps.cd.onDrawFrame(javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10)+490)
03-30 16:27:34.462 2698-2698/? A/AEE/DEBUG:     #09 pc 01686221  /data/app/com.pretlist.p2p.app-1/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0x9d1000) (void com.nokia.maps.ac$b.run()+5484)
03-30 16:27:34.462 2698-2698/? A/AEE/DEBUG:     #10 pc 000e6531  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+64)
03-30 16:27:34.462 2698-2698/? A/AEE/DEBUG:     #11 pc 003eadcf  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+170)
03-30 16:27:34.462 2698-2698/? A/AEE/DEBUG:     #12 pc 0010276c  [stack:2635]
```

Comment: Can you share the complete stack trace?

Comment: play services version?

Comment: Google Play services  - com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87

Comment: @SanjitKumarMishra added log dump

Comment: Would you be able to post the snippet of code which causes this issue (i.e. sequence of calls to HERE SDK)?

Comment: @AndrewJC as I suspect, issue is on here map initialization. I have exactly same steps which are mentioned here https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-premium/topics/app-simple-android-studio.html .  For Cluster, I am creating and adding cluster in onEngineInitializationCompleted event.

Answer (score 0):

HERE provides new location related APIs, SDKs, tools and solutions.

For your use case you need to use the latest HERE Android Mobile SDK.

Please look at our developer portal and documentation at:

https://developer.here.com/